# Get id of an record on click of checkbox

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, ajax

I need to get the id of an record on the click of checkbox. I am able to get the id in outputText though.

```
public class AjaxUtility
{
    public List<Account> accList{get;set;}
    public List<Wrap> wrapList{get;set;}
    public AjaxUtility()
    {
        fillDataInTable();
    }
    public void fillDataInTable()
    {
        wrapList = new List<wrap>();
        for(Account acc : [Select id, name, phone, AccountNumber, fax From Account Order By LastModifiedDate DESC Limit 5])
        {
            wrapList.add(new wrap(acc));
        }
    }
    public class Wrap
    {
        public Account acc{get;set;}
        public boolean checkbox{get;set;}
        public Wrap(Account acc)
        {
            this.acc = acc;
            checkbox = false;
        }
    }
}

    <apex:page controller="AjaxUtility" id="pg" setup="true">
    <apex:form id="fm">
    <script src="/soap/ajax/37.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!urlFor($Resource.ActiveWidget, '/ActiveWidgets/runtime/lib/aw.js')}" />
            <apex:stylesheet value="{!urlFor($Resource.ActiveWidget, '/ActiveWidgets/runtime/styles/aqua/aw.css')}"/>
    <apex:actionFunction action="{!fillDataInTable}" name="callMyAF" reRender="pbt"/>
        <apex:pageBlock title="MyAccount" id="pb">
        <apex:pageBlockButtons id="pbb" location="top">
            <apex:commandButton onclick="saveData();return false;" value="Save" id="save"/>
            <apex:commandButton onclick="editData();return false;" value="Edit" id="edit"/>
            <apex:commandButton onclick="deleteData();return false;" value="Delete" id="delete"/>
            <apex:commandButton onclick="updateData();return false;" value="Update" id="update"/>
            <apex:commandButton onclick="clearData();return false;" value="Clear" id="clear"/>
            <apex:commandButton onclick="cancelData();return false;" value="Cancel" id="cancel"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Create New Account" collapsible="true" id="pbs1" >
                <table id="tbl">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Account Name <input id="name" type="text"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Account Number <input id="AccountNumber" type="text"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Phone  <input id="fax" type="text"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Fax <input id="phone" type="text"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Recent Account" id="pbs2" columns="1">
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!wrapList}" var="row" id="pbt" >
                    <apex:column headerValue="Action">
                        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!row.checkbox}" id="chk" onchange="check();">
                            <apex:outputText value="{!row.acc.Id}" />
                        </apex:inputCheckbox>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column value="{!row.acc.name}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!row.acc.AccountNumber}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!row.acc.Phone}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!row.acc.fax}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
        <script>
            sforce.connection.sessionId='{!getSessionId()}';
            onLoad();
            function onLoad(){
                document.getElementById("pg:fm:pb:pbb:edit").style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById("pg:fm:pb:pbb:cancel").style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById("pg:fm:pb:pbb:update").style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById("pg:fm:pb:pbb:delete").style.display = 'none';
            }
            function check(){
                debugger;
                var count =0;
                for(i=0;i<5;i++)
                {
                    if(document.getElementById("pg:fm:pb:pbs2:pbt:" + [i] +":chk").checked ==true)
                    count++;
                }
                if(count == 1)
                    chkEdit();
                else if(count == 0)
                    countZero();  
                else  
                    chkDel();
            }
            function countZero(){
                document.getElementById('pg:fm:pb:pbb:save').style.display = 'inline';
                document.getElementById('pg:fm:pb:pbb:clear').style.display = 'inline';
                document.getElementById('pg:fm:pb:pbb:edit').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('pg:fm:pb:pbb:update').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('pg:fm:pb:pbb:cancel').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('pg:fm:pb:pbb:delete').style.display = 'none';
            }
            function chkEdit(){
                document.getElementById('pg:fm:pb:pbb:edit').style.display = 'inline';
                document.getElementById('pg:fm:pb:pbb:update').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('pg:fm:pb:pbb:cancel').style.display = 'inline';
                document.getElementById('pg:fm:pb:pbb:save').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('pg:fm:pb:pbb:clear').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('pg:fm:pb:pbb:delete').style.display = 'inline';
            }
            function chkDel(){
                document.getElementById('pg:fm:pb:pbb:save').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('pg:fm:pb:pbb:clear').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('pg:fm:pb:pbb:update').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('pg:fm:pb:pbb:edit').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('pg:fm:pb:pbb:cancel').style.display = 'inline';
                document.getElementById('pg:fm:pb:pbb:delete').style.display = 'inline';

            }
            function saveData(){
                debugger;
                var acc = new sforce.SObject("Account");
                acc.Name = document.getElementById("name").value;
                acc.accountnumber= document.getElementById("AccountNumber").value;
                acc.fax = document.getElementById("fax").value;
                acc.phone= document.getElementById("phone").value;
                var insert = sforce.connection.create([acc]);
                callMyAF();
                clearData();
            }
            function cancelData(){
                for(i=0;i<5;i++){
                    document.getElementById("pg:fm:pb:pbs2:pbt:" + [i] +":chk").checked = false;
                }
                document.getElementById('pg:fm:pb:pbb:save').style.display = 'inline';
                document.getElementById('pg:fm:pb:pbb:clear').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('pg:fm:pb:pbb:update').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('pg:fm:pb:pbb:edit').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('pg:fm:pb:pbb:cancel').style.display = 'inline';
                document.getElementById('pg:fm:pb:pbb:delete').style.display = 'none';
            }
            function editData(){
                document.getElementById('pg:fm:pb:pbb:save').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('pg:fm:pb:pbb:clear').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('pg:fm:pb:pbb:update').style.display = 'inline';
                document.getElementById('pg:fm:pb:pbb:edit').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('pg:fm:pb:pbb:cancel').style.display = 'inline';
                document.getElementById('pg:fm:pb:pbb:delete').style.display = 'none';
                var tblObj = document.getElementById("tbl");
        /*        for(i=0;i<tblObj.length;i++){
                    for(var j=0;j<tblObj.rows[i].cells.length;j++){
                        tblObj.rows[i].cells[j]. = alertInnerHTML;
                    }
                }*/
            }
            function updateData(){
                for(i=0;i<5;i++){
                        document.getElementById("pg:fm:pb:pbs2:pbt:" + [i] +":chk").checked = false;
                    }
                document.getElementById('pg:fm:pb:pbb:save').style.display = 'inline';
                document.getElementById('pg:fm:pb:pbb:clear').style.display = 'inline';
                document.getElementById('pg:fm:pb:pbb:update').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('pg:fm:pb:pbb:edit').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('pg:fm:pb:pbb:cancel').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('pg:fm:pb:pbb:delete').style.display = 'none';
            }
            function deleteData(){
                debugger;
                countZero();
                var arr = [];
                for(i=0;i<5;i++){
                    if(document.getElementById("pg:fm:pb:pbs2:pbt:" + [i] +":chk").checked ==true)
                        arr.push(document.getElementById("pg:fm:pb:pbs2:pbt:" + [i] +":chk"));
                }
                alert('array = '+arr);
                var result = sforce.connection.deleteIds(arr);
            }

            function clearData(){
                debugger;
                document.getElementById("name").value = '';
                document.getElementById("AccountNumber").value = '';
                document.getElementById("fax").value = '';
                document.getElementById("phone").value = '';
            }
        </script>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: And where you need the Id, Javascript, class?

Comment: in javascript because I have to delete the records from page only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `javascript` method pass the Id as parameter

```
check('{!row.acc.Id}');
```

and in the method get this

```
function check(accId){
                debugger;
```

Comment: thanks its working but now how shall I clear the array. I have taken one var =[] to collect the ids of records. If I click a record and then uncheck it the id should also be removed from array

Comment: @Anzar just do simply `arr = [];` . Also if this solve your problem you can accept this answer.

Comment: @TusharSharma where should I empty it? because check function is called when checkbox is clicked and based on the no of checked checkboxes other methods are called

Comment: @Anzar you will get better result if you post a new question and explain your scenario better.

Answer (score 0):

I think using `<apex:param>` would be a better choice.

Comment: He need that ID in javascript not in apex controller

Comment: @saurabh With apex:param we can send value in controller from page. But I need was to send value in javascript.